# Connecting front end and back end React / Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create an account through my registration form, however I keep on getting this error:

This is my registration form: [image]

However when I press Register, get this error:

```
Commands: npm start
Errors: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Error photo: [image]

Much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Problem solved: Needed to start the React and the Node project on two different terminals, first run the React and then the Node project

Comment: I would need a little more info like, what is the port your server is listening on?. Does your registration backend resides on some other server? Or maybe a code snippet would help.

Comment: Yes, var port = process.env.PORT || 5000 //Port 5000 value
And "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

Comment: You may try replacing  localhost with 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Enable cors in your server

if Node and express
then add cors package and then in the entry point file ( index.js or app.js )

add this along with other imports

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

and then after your app is initialised then add this line

```
app.use(cors());
```

and also add these lines to the header of your request on the react side

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
```

if you are using axios then I suggest you creating a separate file for axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

there you configure your common axios details and import this file instead of the package wherever you using axios on react

If still facing an issue then please copy paste the error as it shows on the network tab

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to this is to run node server.js instead of npm start

Comment: do you have route defined ?

Comment: yes, var Users = require('./routes/Users') // routes: URL

Comment: try add in your server js : 

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});